# Is there a way to enable compatibility mode for all executables in a certain folder and its subfolders?

Tags: windows-7

Pretty much the title says it all; **is there a way to enable compatibility mode for all executables in a certain folder and all its subfolders, even those that don't yet exist (subfolders, as well as executables) without doing it manually (right click/properties/compatibility/...)?**

Anything that would *automate* this process in a way would be useful ...

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it can be done for not-yet-created filesystem objects, as it's probably a property of executables only and I can't see a mechanism for having it inherited on a folder.

What you *should* be able to do is write a batch script that recurses into a directory and sets compatibility mode on any executables it finds.  Said file will need to modify the registry - there needs to be a string value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` for each program to run in compatibility mode, with a value of the form `oldWindowsVersion [setting [setting...]] [privilegeLevel]` - see The "manually via the registry" part of [this forum post](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html) for details.

You would still have to run it manually when new executables appeared, although you might be able to do something cunning with scheduled tasks.